# create rpn expression from infix

Tags: c

I tried to convert a infix notation expression to a postfix notatin (RPN).
here is the function:

```
String createRPN(String infix)
{
     Stack *stack = node_alloc(1); //stack pointer
     stack->next = NULL;
     String ptr; //index
     String RPN = malloc(strlen(infix) + 1);
     String start = RPN;

     for (ptr = infix; *ptr != '\0'; ptr++)
     {
         if (isNum(*ptr) || (*ptr == ' ')) *RPN++ = *ptr;
         else if (*ptr == '(') push(&stack, '(');
         else if (isOper(*ptr))
         {
              while ((stack != NULL) && (stack->value != '('))
              {
                    if (compareOper(stack->value, *ptr)) *RPN++ = pop(&stack);
                    else break;
              }
              push(&stack, *ptr);
         } 
         else if (*ptr == ')')
         {
              while ((stack != NULL) && (stack->value != '(')) *RPN++ = pop(&stack);
              if (stack != NULL) pop(&stack);
         }
         else;
     }
     while (stack != NULL) *RPN++ = pop(&stack);
     *RPN = '\0';

     return start;
}
```

here is the stack code:

```
typedef struct node
{
   int value;
   struct node *next;   
}Stack;

void push(Stack **node, int value)
{
     Stack *temp = node_alloc(1);
     if (temp == NULL) return;
     temp->value = value;
     temp->next = *node;
     *node = temp;
}

int pop(Stack **node)
{
    if (*node == NULL) return 0;

    int num = (*node)->value;
    Stack *temp = (*node)->next;
    free(*node);
    *node = (temp == NULL) ? NULL : temp;

    return num;
}
```

but after i enter the infix string, example:

```
2 * ((3 + 5) + (6 + 2) * 5)
```

the program crashes, I need your help to detect my mistake..

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 String RPN = malloc(sizeof(char*) * strlen(infix));
```

is all wrong.

You're allocating units of `sizeof (char *)` (pointer to character) when you should be thinking in plain characters. Also you're not allowing for the terminating character.

You need:

```
String RPN = malloc(strlen(infix) + 1);
```

There's no point in (ever) multiplying by `sizeof (char)`, since it's guaranteed to be 1.

Comment: Thx, but it still dont work, and for the size of the string (the infix expression is already bigger than the postfix because it have "()" and the postfix doesnt include them).. but the real problem i noticed it i didnt return the string from createRPN, so i changed it but the program still crashes..